# Term for a rectangle-like arrangement of three line segments

Tags: terminology, euclidean-geometry, rectangles

Is there a proper geometric term for the class of line arrangement demonstrated here? [image: four possible arrangements of three line segments]

i.e. rectangles with one edge missing, or put differently, any rectilinear arrangements of three segments.